# Syntax error authenticating tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I am quite new to installing modules on python. I'm trying to get started with Tweepy but I'm hitting an error.

I have run

```
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(MYCONSUMERKEY, MYCONSUMERSECRET)
```

But the following error is returned:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(MYCONSUMERKEY, MYCONSUMERSECRET)
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here? Im using Python 2.7 on OSX El Capitan

Comment: Where is the `^` actually pointing in your error message? Your formatting was all messed up.

Comment: Right under the last character of my consumer secret as you have it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have your Twitter Apps credentials (otherwise, nothing will work).

Use the following portion of code (assuming you have the required credentials)

```
import tweepy

# Fill this up with the Twitter Apps Credentials (get them @ apps.twitter.com)
consumer_key = "Your consumer Key"
consumer_secret = "Your consumer Key Secret"
access_token = "Your access Token"
access_token_secret = "Your access Token Secret"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

print "User Name:", api.me().name
print "Account (@):", api.me().screen_name
```

With this, you have the basic framework to start interacting with the Twitter API using Tweepy (the last two lines, based on your Twitter credentials, should print your name and @username in Twitter.